# connection.setRequestProperty and excplicitly writing to the urloutputstream are they same?

Tags: java, urlconnection

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/comment");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Is

```
connection.setRequestProperty(key, value);
```

the same as

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.write("key=" + value);
writer.close();
```

?

If not, please correct me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not. The `URLConnection#setRequestProperty()` sets a request **header**. For HTTP requests you can find all possible headers [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

The `writer` just writes the request **body**. In case of `POST` with urlencoded content, you'd normally write the query string into the request body instead of appending it to the request URI like as in `GET`.

That said, `connection.setDoOutput(true);` already implicitly sets the request method to `POST` in case of a HTTP URI (because it's implicitly required to write to the request body then), so doing an `connection.setRequestMethod("POST");` afterwards is unnecessary.